# In the google_sign_in install instructions, what does "register your application" mean?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am learning flutter and trying to use the google_sign_in package. The [package instructions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in) say that I have to "[register your application](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android)" but that link resolves to the [firebase homepage](https://firebase.google.com/?platform=android). Not very helpful. So, I don't know what I am supposed to do to "register my application".

I do not want to use firebase. I want the user to login at google so I can then use the [googleapis](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis) package to fetch a spreadsheet that is owned by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit the [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard) dashboard. Click on `+ Enable APIs and Services`. Search for either `Sheets` or `Drive` depending on which API you'd like to use, and click through to that API's page, where you can enable and/or `try this api`.

Having enabled it, go back to the dashboard where it should now be listed. In the left hand pane is `Credentials` to create app credentials, if required.

Comment: Ok, so, I assume that before I do any of this I should create a new google cloud project, correct? Is the idea that a flutter app needs to have a corresponding google cloud project, to use google services?

Comment: Yes, looks like it. I have a drop-down, top, left with 3 tessellated hexagons (?), which opens a dialog with a `+`.